# Creating models in JS with Async calls to an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm familiar with creating models in a synchronous environment like PHP or Ruby, but doing this in JS is pretty different.

Here's a model I've just started on and am stumped on how I'm going to return my value.

```
var Activity =  {
    get: function(params) {
        if (params.id) {
            return Activity.getById(params.id);
        }
    },

    getById: function(id) {
        $.get('/activities', {id: id})
            .success(function(activity) {
                return activity[0];
            });
    }
};
```

In `.success()` I want to return my result back to `getById`, but since it's in a callback, I'm not really sure where it goes.

Anyway, when I run this in the console I just get `undefined`.

What can I do here to return in this async style?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you cannot just return here.

One way would be to call a handler function with a corresponding parameter:

```
getById: function(id) {
    $.get('/activities', {id: id})
        .success(function(activity) {
            successFunction(activity[0]);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add a callback:

```
getById: function(id, callback) {
    $.get('/activities', {id: id})
        .success(function(activity) {
            callback(activity[0]);
        });
}
```

In async programming, callbacks is how you "wait" for it to come back.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use callback, use promises or Deferred if you want "kind of" sync code. (meaning it looks sync using return even though it is async behind the scene)

You basically just missed a `return` in your code:

```
var Activity =  {
    get: function(params) {
        if (params.id) {
            return Activity.getById(params.id).then(function(activity){
              console.log(activity)
            });
        }
    },

    getById: function(id) {
        return $.get('/activities', {id: id})// You need to return this!
            .success(function(activity) {
                return activity[0];
            });
    }
};
```

You can now just call it like that:

```
Activity.get({id: 5}).then(function(activity){JSON.stringify(activity)})
```

This would log two versions, the object one and then the stringified.

---

See the last example from there: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

```
var request = $.ajax( url, { dataType: "json" } ),
  chained = request.then(function( data ) {
    return $.ajax( url2, { data: { user: data.userId } } );
  });

chained.done(function( data ) {
  // data retrieved from url2 as provided by the first request
});
```

You can use `then` or `done`, but if you use `done` then you won't be able to do anything else afterwards, while using `then` allows you to chain as much as you want to.